# How to create custom task list view targeting only "Assigned To" user / group programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

I have one `document library`. And a workflow attached to it, when this workflow is executed a `task` gets created which is assigned to users.

I want to have a `view` which shows the `tasks` that are assigned to `current logged in user`.

And I strictly need this from code behind.

Is it possible with event receiver code in the feature and how ?

Reference-http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2009/12/create-sharepoint-list-view.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event receiver is not a choice for this. If you are sure about the `Task` List name and strictly want to do this with `Code Behind`.

Then I think you should develop a `Visual WebPart` which queries the task list with a filter of Current User, and all the items.

You can read [Walkthrough: Creating a Web Part for SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ee231546.aspx)

Comment: Hello Asad,

I'd used the CAML Query for the same-
<Or>
  <Membership Type=\"CurrentUserGroups\">
    <FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"/>
  </Membership>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"></FieldRef>
    <Value Type=\"Integer\">
      <UserID/>
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Or>
Reference- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544234(v=office.15).aspx

It's working fine.
So can you please let me know why the Event receiver is not a choice for this ?

Comment: This looks good. You will need to you use in Visual Webpart.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this CAML Query we can do the same-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544234(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/52234)

Comment: Ohh, See this comment for the same.
<Or> <Membership Type=\"CurrentUserGroups\"> <FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"/> </Membership> <Eq> <FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"></FieldRef> <Value Type=\"Integer\"> <UserID/> </Value> </Eq> </Or>